# Crystal Report SetDataSource crash

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017, .net-3.5

My project was developed by Visual Studio 2013 which is using Crystal Report under SP21. Currently I migrated to use Visual Studio 2017 and installed Crystal Report SP24. The application is able to execute without any issue. However, once I print report by Crystal Report, w3wp.exe was crashed. It is happening in my localhost.

```
          rptGrn.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/GRNRecords.rpt"));
      rptGrn.SetDataSource(SSRecordHdrs); //error
      rptGrn.Subreports["GRNDetails"].SetDataSource(lsDtls); //error
```

I tried the solution by add setting in web.config but no luck on this and it didn't working.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>    
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

I have scratch my head one week for this issue. I'm appreciate any help or comment that giving clues to solve this issue.

Thank you very much.

Setup:
 - WebForm application
 - .NET 3.5
 - Visual Studio 2017
 - IIS 10 (Localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suffering for a week, I found the root cause is Crystal Report SP21 afterward is unable to using ADO.NET.

Kindly refer points(5) for SP21:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Solution I found is:
Create a virtual machine by installing Crystal Report under SP21 and deploy the project over virtual machine.

Take note:
.NET framework over 3.5 will not having this issue.

If anyone are developing by .NET 3.5 framework above and maybe able solve it by adding

```
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

to web/app config. I tried this method but no luck for me.

Good luck for anyone having this issue.